# How to load a nested list from a file without quotation marks?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, save

I'm supposed to create a "stock control" system for a software wholesaler for an module assignment. I have created the program, but I'm having trouble saving stuff permanently. The program consists of nested lists like the following:

```
[["Ms Office", "CD", 7, "Microsoft"], ["Acrobat Reader", "DVD", 12, "Adobe"], ["Norton Antivirus", "DVD", 24, "Symantec"]]
```

I can save them to a text document in the format

```
['Ms Office', 'CD', 7, 'Microsoft']
['Acrobat Reader', 'DVD', 12, 'Adobe']
['Norton Antivirus', 'DVD', 24, 'Symantec']
```

But when I try to load it back as a list in the same format, I end up with quotation marks separating each entry like so:

```
["['Ms Office', 'CD', 7, 'Microsoft']", "['Acrobat Reader', 'DVD', 12, 'Adobe']", "['Norton Antivirus', 'DVD', 24, 'Symantec']"]
```

I just need to get rid of the double quotes surrounding each item in the list now.
The code I'm using to load this file:

```
filename = open('Appexstock.txt', 'r')
contents = filename.read()
thelist = [name for name in contents.split('\n') if name.split('"') if name]
filename.close()
```

I've searched for hours online and have tried everything but I still can't find a way to make it work. I've seen a lot of people suggest the CSV module, but I have no idea how to apply it to my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
with open('Appexstock.txt') as f:
    lis = [literal_eval(line) for line in f]
...     
>>> lis
[['Ms Office', 'CD', 7, 'Microsoft'], ['Acrobat Reader', 'DVD', 12, 'Adobe'], ['Norton Antivirus', 'DVD', 24, 'Symantec']]
```

To store python object it is better to use the [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) module:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> data = [["Ms Office", "CD", 7, "Microsoft"], ["Acrobat Reader", "DVD", 12, "Adobe"], ["Norton Antivirus", "DVD", 24, "Symantec"]]
with open('my_data', 'w') as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)
...     
with open('my_data') as f:
    print pickle.load(f)
...     
[['Ms Office', 'CD', 7, 'Microsoft'], ['Acrobat Reader', 'DVD', 12, 'Adobe'], ['Norton Antivirus', 'DVD', 24, 'Symantec']]
```

Comment: I need to save the list the list loaded from the file into a list variable that can be used in later functions. like
thelist = [['Ms Office', 'CD', 7, 'Microsoft'], ['Acrobat Reader', 'DVD', 12, 'Adobe'], ['Norton Antivirus', 'DVD', 24, 'Symantec']]

when I try to do this with the pickle code I get an error msg:
"thelist = pickle.load(f)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface"

I don't know if I'm doing it right. I'm a beginner to python and coding altogether

Comment: @user2802349 I am already doing that in the first code, in the second one just do: `lis = pickle.load(data, f)`.

Comment: @user2802349 What is `f` in your code?(`f` should be a file object) It works fine for me.

Comment: OK. I'm not sure what's wrong. My function to save the list:

def savelists():
    data = thelist
    with open('my_data', 'w') as f:
        pickle.dump(data, f)

My code to load data:
import pickle
with open('my_data') as f:
    thelist = pickle.load(data, f)
print(thelist)

Should I make 'data' a global variable?

Comment: @user2802349 Don't paste code in comments, it is not readable. Use http://ideone.com

Comment: @user2802349 You just need: `pickle.load(f)`, don't pass `data` to `load`.

Comment: @user2802349 Use: `thelist = pickle.load(f)`

Comment: I changed it to that. Now it says "    thelist = pickle.load(f)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface"

Comment: @user2802349 I've no idea what are you doing, this works fine on my system: http://pastebin.com/iBbMcyE4

Comment: Something is wrong i guess. Even by using just the bit of code that you just sent to test it out I get an error that says "    pickle.dump(data, f)
TypeError: must be str, not bytes"

Comment: @user2802349 You're on py3.x?

Comment: python 3.3.2 :( Been working on this part for days. Is there anyway to load if off the text file in the beginning without the quotes? As in without importing any modules?

Comment: @user2802349 open file in binary mode:  `open('my_data', 'wb')` and ` `open('my_data', 'rb')`

Comment: @user2802349 There's no need to re-invent the wheel, if an standard module is already available then use it. :)

Comment: The same error message shows up: "thelist = pickle.load(f)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface"

The whole point of this program is to create a stock control system for a software wholesaler. I've got the whole program done. Around 250 lines of code. Everything we've learned in class. We also learned how to save basic stuff in text files. But I have nested lists in my program that need to stay changed (if changes are made) when the program is closed and loaded up to be used in functions when the program is opened again. This was the only way I could come up with of doing it.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help though :) Meant a lot:)